# Regular expression to extract number

Tags: regex

I have log in the below format and I am trying extract 2394528 from the line by  below command 
and its not retreving any results

```
 0140928.log:2014/09/28 06:45:00,911 Info   CS Traffic: secureserver ABC:  2394528 / 000 

 20140928.log:2014/09/28 07:00:00,910 Info   CS Traffic: secureserver ABC:  2397206 / 000
```

Command:

```
grep ":\s\+(.{7}\d+)\s+/" 20140928.log.
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: One bug is you have `\+` (a literal plus sign) instead of `+`. So `\s\+` only matches one whitespace followed by a plus sign, and there aren't any of those.

Comment: `.*?ABC:\s*?(\d+)\s*?/` explanation: find anything until ABC:. \s*? find any whitespace(s). (\d+) find the numbers and group for retrieving later. \s* find any whitespace(s). find /. In simple terms, find any number(s) between ABC: and / with may or may not whitespace(s) inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
/\d+(?=\s\/)/g
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/hD8yY9/1) Remove the `g` modifier if you want a single match.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below grep command with `-o`, `-P` parameters.

```
grep -oP ':\s+\K\d{7}(?=\s+\/)' file
```

**OR**

Try the below if the length of the number varies.

```
grep -oP ':\s+\K\d+(?=\s+\/)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` you can do it as follows:

```
sed 's~^.*: *\([0-9]*\) /.*$~\1~' file
2394528
2397206
```

This `sed` regex matches everything from start to `:<space>` and then captures number coming next in back reference variable `\1` and then matches till the end. In replacement it uses back reference `\1` in order to just output the number.